# SortedList IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position on remove last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, sortedlist

I have endless scrolling RecyclerView. Data is stored in SortedList. When user would scroll down, loading item appears and disappears when next 10 items are loaded. I am getting following error while removing LoaderItem:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 10(offset:-1).state:11
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5512)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5448)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5444)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3551)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3030)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java)
```

This is my code:

**Adapter:**

```
val battles = SortedList(RecyclerViewItem::class.java, object : SortedListAdapterCallback<RecyclerViewItem>(this)
{
    override fun areItemsTheSame(item1 : RecyclerViewItem?, item2 : RecyclerViewItem?) : Boolean
    {
        if (item1 is Battle && item2 is Battle && item1.id == item2.id) return true
        if (item1 is LoaderItem && item2 is LoaderItem) return true
        return false
    }

    override fun compare(o1 : RecyclerViewItem?, o2 : RecyclerViewItem?) : Int =
    if (o1 is Battle && o2 is Battle)
    {
        when
        {
            o1.points > o2.points  -> 1
            o1.points == o2.points -> 0
            else            -> -1
        }
    }
    else -1
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem : RecyclerViewItem?, newItem : RecyclerViewItem?) : Boolean = if (oldItem is LoaderItem) true
    else (oldItem as Battle).points == (newItem as Battle).points

})

fun removeLoadingItem()
{
    (0 until battles.size()).filter { battles[it] is LoaderItem }.forEach { battles.removeItemAt(it) }
}

fun addDownloadedItems(battles : List<Battle>)
{
    this.battles.addAll(battles)
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
override fun displayDownloadedBattles(battles : List<Battle>, isMore : Boolean) {
    pbLoader.visibility = View.GONE
    isLoading = false
    if (isMore)
        adapter.removeLoadingItem()
    adapter.addDownloadedItems(battles)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  (0 until battles.size()).filter { battles[it] is LoaderItem }.forEach { battles.removeItemAt(it) }
```

This fragment contain error: index sequence is incorrect after first removing.
You may cycle downto.
Why not use

```
battles.filter { it is LoaderItem }.forEach { battles.remove(it) }
```